# Could electromagnets ever compete with the power of an antimatter annihilation engine?

Tags: strength, electromagnetism, engines

So to make this easier to read, I've been using a few terms I'll explain really quick

**"MPP"**: *(maximum physical potential)*

**"MASS"**: *(maximum atomic structure strength)*

According to my research, a piston engine made of metal with the highest theoretically possible specific strength, and fueled by antimatter annihilation, would have the strength of hundreds of thousands of nuclear explosions, but from what I gather, even with superpositioned MASS-metal as the material, the theoretical MPP strength of an electromagnetic actuator put to the same task as the antimatter engine would be vastly weaker, capping at roughly 10 teslas due to "core saturation". I've heard about "bitter electromagnets" but can't find anything on their maximum theoretical strength. **Is the peak technological potential of mechanical strength truly limited to piston-driving antimatter annihilation, or is there any way electromagnets can scale to vaguely equivalent power?**

Comment: Science fiction isn't engineering

Comment: Where can I get some *antimatter annihilation*?  It sounds like the coolest, most dangerous substance.  Antimatter is bad, so  antimatter annihilation has to be so much worse.  Or is this like infinity?

Comment: @ StainlessSteelRat I'm going to assume you're not mocking me here -"antimatter annihilation" is short for "antimatter/matter annihilation", which according to the Atomic Rockets website, is the more correct way of saying, "touching antimatter with matter and making a big explosion" XD

Comment: You have to put the @name to send messages.  We be simple engineers and not up on the latest buzz words.  So slight mocking.  And the answer is no!  Real world governed by matter and losses can not compete with antimatter.